# How to stop a sequence according to the command line

Tags: python

I have to print the sequence `seq 100 1000 | python3 filename '/1{3}/q'`.

`seq 100 1000 | python3 filename '/1{3}/q'` ->

Prints the sequence from 100 to 1000 but should shout printing the sequence when it reaches a number where the digit 1 is printed 3 times in the same line that's 111.

Sequence prints automatically. My file need to read the command line and should make the sequence stop printing when the sequence reaches 111.

I don't get how to read and search for the number(prints the digit 3 times) according to the command line?

I don't where to start from or what to use?[https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IftC.png][1]

This is the code

```
import sys
import re

slippy_command = sys.argv[1]

line_number = 0
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    line_number += 1
    if line == '':
        break
    print(line, end = '')

 if slippy_command[-3:] == "}/q":
```

Don't know what to do after this?

Comment: It looks like everything between the first and last forward slash is a regular expression. If I'm right, you'd split that out, compile it, then match it against each line.

Comment: You posted [a question just like this earlier that got closed](/q/73367808/4518341) (now deleted). Please, read [ask]. You need to ask a specific question and proof-read (e.g. *"should shout printing").

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an attempt to revive a question that was closed and deleted instead of fixing it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73367808/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think I was able to provide an adequate answer to a not so great question. I think it is salvageable if OP cares to take the time to do so. Otherwise, I agree with closing it.

Answer (score 1):

As it currently stands, your algorithm will loop to the end of the sequence.

You could include a check for your command line argument before the loop and use the regex library 're' to compile a pattern to compare against the string.

```python
import re 

pattern = None

if sys.argv[1]:

    pattern = re.compile(sys.argv[1])

line_number = 0

while True:

    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    line_number += 1

    if pattern and pattern.match(line.strip()):
        
        break 
    
    print(line, end = '')
```

Comment: The loop prints the whole sequence won't stop at 111

Comment: Does it not end at the end of the sequence? That is what I mean. So placing the if-statement at the end wouldn't have any impact on the loop. It will continue until there is no more input from stdin.

Comment: I just noticed the if statement is partially indented by a space or 2. If that was intentional, your indentations need to be consistent. If you indent a block by 2 spaces and then another block by 4 spaces, the Python interpreter will get mad at you.